If $a,b \in \mathbb F_{2^r+1}^\times$, then $a = b^n$ or $b = a^m$ (for $m,n \in \mathbb Z$)

Suppose that $p$ is a Fermat prime, i.e., $p$ has the form $2^r + 1$ for some positive integer $r$, and let $F$ denote the field with $p$ elements. Let $a, b$ be two elements of the multiplicative group $F^\times$. Show that either $a = b^n$ for some integer $n$, or $b = a^m$ for some integer $m$.

We know that the cyclic group $F^\times$ has $p-1 = 2^r$ elements, and so is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/2^r\mathbb Z,+)$. The problem is equivalent to showing that for any $a,b \in (\mathbb Z/2^r\mathbb Z,+)$, either $a = nb$ or $b = ma$. I could consider the maps $\phi_a, \phi_b: \mathbb Z/2^r\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2^r\mathbb Z$ given by $\phi_a(g) = ga$ and $\phi_b(g) = gb$. Then, we have to show either $a\in \operatorname{Im} \phi_b$ or $b\in \operatorname{Im} \phi_a$. How should one go about this?

The subgroup generated by $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the set of multiples of $\gcd(a,n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Note that order of any element of $\mathbb{F}^{\times}$ must be of the form $2^k$, where $k\leq r$. Thus
$$o(a) = 2^{k_1} \quad \text{and} \quad o(b)=2^{k_2},$$
$k_1, k_2\leq r$. Suppose $k_1\leq k_2$. Then it is easy to see that the subgroup generated by $a$, i.e. $<a>$ must be a subgroup of subgroup generated by $b$, i.e. $<b>$. If not, then, anyway $<b>$ is going to have a subgroup of order $2^{k_1}$ which is different from the subgroup $<a>$ which also has $2^{k_1}$ elements thus producing two different subgroups of same order in a cyclic group. Thus $<a>$ is a subgroup of $<b>$ and hence,
$a=b^{m}$ for some integer $m$.
If $k_2\leq k_1$, then the same arguments would yield that $b=a^n$ for some integer $n$.
